# WIX: The product is not uninstalled fully (the files from system is not removed)

Tags: windows, wix, windows-installer

I have problem when the uninstalling my app is not removing the files.
I find out that there when app is uninstalling in log it prints:

...
`MSI (s) (0C:84) [11:39:07:836]: Disallowing uninstallation of component: {51DB6066-AFCD-5A03-BE34-09E197799057} since another client exists`
...

Then I find out by using WiX Toolset has the API called DTF (mentioned in [Wix toolset: complete cleanup after "disallowing uninstallation of component since another client exists"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26739524/wix-toolset-complete-cleanup-after-disallowing-uninstallation-of-component-sin)), and i executed query in LinqPad (c# Statement):

(F4 press to import namespaces and additiona reference)

```
//using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;
//using System.Linq;
// <ref>"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.9\SDK\
         Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.dll"</ref> 


var client = ComponentInstallation.AllComponents
    .Where (c => c.ComponentCode == "{72ED6979-0AAD-317C-A25C-AB9A121E6D30}")
    .Select(c => c);
client.Dump();
```

that there is old recods:
[image]

I cant remove them using "msiexec /x {GUID}" becouse these products is marked as "IsInstalled=False".

**So how to remove these old records?**

Comment: I found features by name in registry and deleted them from:
    [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Features\...   But the uninstalling proces still not removes files and same info messages are shown in log. Theres is still left the root ProductInstallation item with 0 features items.

Comment: You can run [this script](https://github.com/glytzhkof/all/blob/master/MsiHtmlReport-Mini-V6-SearchEngine.vbs) to find all installed MSI pacakges on the box. Then search for the product code you found to see what the product name is. You can then uninstall the product in question - if it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 0):

**Disallowing uninstallation of component: {51DB6066-AFCD-5A03-BE34-09E197799057} since another client exists**

This generally means that there is one or more products currently installed on your system which reference this component.

Have you made sure that there is no other product on the system which references this component?

You dont want to do this sort of clean-up as windows installer handles all of this without any sort of  user intervention.

Have you installed an older version of your product earlier  or is this file installed by a merge module?

Comment: Hello, I know what it means. The installing product does not handle these features override and they remains as duplicates. Because of that the files are not removed. I tried older versions installation but it does not helps. These records might be the consequence of custom setup when developing product (might be, that I changed GUID`s for some products and installed this custom version, I am not sure).

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what exactly do you mean when you say "Feature overrides"?  In the windows installer world, if a component is registered on the system, it is always associated with a product.  Have you tried figuring out the other clients which are associated with the component. You can do that by making use of the API:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Comment: See my images in story question, there is features associated with product. So for some PC we resolved, there was folder missing and uninstallation was failing. But for my PC some registries are broken, becouse I cant fix it.