# Windows installer popping up repair mechanism

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have a Windows installer package which causes Windows repair mechanism to pop up randomly. From the event viewer logs, I see the below message

`Detection of product 'Product ID'. feature 'feature_name' failed during request for component 'component id'`

However apart from this I don't see any other messages in the Event viewer's Application logs. According to this MSDN article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/searching-for-a-broken-feature-or-component, I see that the above message should be followed by another message given below

`Detection of product 'MyProduct', feature 'MyFeature', component 'MyComponent' failed`

But I don't see this message in the Event Viewer logs and I am confused by this issue on how to fix it. Any idea on what is causing this?

Comment: Would be useful to know what product this relates to. Is it your own product? I'd say the primary self-repair causes are **`1)`** bad MSI packages, **`2)`** external factors deleting files, **`3)`** Windows design changes that trigger latent package problems ([list from self-repair explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263)). You must let us know what files or resources these components point to for us to know anything more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

***Self-Repair***: This is self-repair. I have written a lot about it before:

- [More than you want to know about self-repair](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57717363/129130)
- **`1)`** [Self-repair explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501028/how-can-i-determine-what-causes-repeated-windows-installer-self-repair/6066263#6066263), **`2)`** [Self-repair solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45716108/what-do-i-do-when-launching-an-application-triggers-repeating-endless-windows-i/45716110#45716110) (section 5 here), **`3)`** [Self-repair avoidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828724/how-do-i-avoid-triggering-msi-self-repair-with-my-wix-msi-package/45828725#45828725)

***Cause***: Essentially a key path check on application launch reveals a missing resource. Self-repair ensues to correct the situation (put file or registry key in place). Sometimes the repair fails for various reasons as explained in above link - and keeps repeating endlessly (from [various triggers](https://web.archive.org/web/20210228214048/https://community.broadcom.com/symantecenterprise/communities/community-home/librarydocuments/viewdocument?DocumentKey=b3b5c112-2109-427e-a5b9-74dd4bb60fd4&CommunityKey=41d8253b-a238-4563-8718-ed7623beafbc&tab=librarydocuments)).

> ***Shortlist Debugging***: Self-repair is a simple concept, but can be quite difficult to wrap your head around to solve reliably at times. Some
> first things to try:
>
> - ***Verify Problem***: It is very important to estimate whether this problem is a real one or a developer box problem. Test on virtuals.
> - ***Anti-Virus***: I would try to disable my anti-virus or security suite and then try to launch the product. You should obviously first
>   scan the files to verify the are not flagged as dangerous.
> - ***Advertised Shortcut***: I would also try to launch the file in question directly from the installation folder without using a
>   shortcut ([see section 5.2 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45716110/129130)).

---

You can determine what MSI package this relates to as follows:

1. [***Find product name for product GUID***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56999318/129130). Use this script to find the product name for the product GUID you see in the event log. You know what product you launch, but you can trigger self-repair of other products by launching your own.
2. [***Find what product a component belongs to***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52693733/129130). Use this script to look up what product(s) (there can be more than one) have a particular MSI component in use.

Find these VBScripts here as well: https://github.com/glytzhkof/all

Comment: Steve Asmul Thank you for your answer but the issue is there that the event logs are not specifying what is missing in the system. I have seen issues related to where MSI complains that the file is missing etc. But in this case MSI self repair mechanism is popping up randomly in the system. When there are no changes in the product that has been made.

Comment: Yes, this is quite common. It has to do with interference with other products or the system in various ways. Try to take the information from the event log and work out exactly what product this relates to. You can find the product name from the product guid using the script above, or use the component guid and the second script. Then let us know what file or resource this related to.