# Malformed \p{X} character escape in Powershell

Tags: powershell, escaping

I have a comparison statement using `-match` in PS script

```
$propValue = (Get-ItemProperty "Registry::$($c.Name)" -Name "$($p)")."$($p)"
$productName =  "C:\Program Files (x86)\MyApplication\MyApp"
if ($propValue -match $productName) 
{
      // Do something
}
```

On execution, the script throws error as Malformed \p{X} character escape in Powershell.
What is happening here? How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the full error message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-match` is a regex operator, and `\p{X}` is a regex escape sequence used to describe unicode blocks.

What happens here is likely that you have a string value like

```
sometext\p{b8ee6b4b-fefe-4f77-916f-cb8df996599d}
```

listed in the registry, and so the regex engine will recognize the `p{...}` sequence and throw an error after determining that `b8ee6b4b-fefe-4f77-916f-cb8df996599d` is not a valid unicode block descriptor.

Escape the value of `$productName` before using it as a regex pattern and it'll work as you expect:

```
if ($propValue -match [regex]::Escape($productName)) 
{
      // Do something
}
```