# Is there an alternative to GUID when using msiexec to uninstall an application?

Tags: powershell, installation, uninstallation, windows-installer

We're currently using a GUID to identify the application when running our uninstall script which contains msiexec. The problem I'm having is the GUID changes every time I install the latest version of the application, so I was wondering if there is a different way that I can identify our application running using msiexec?

Comment: cant you target the msi with option to uninstall?

Comment: Which GUID are you referring to?

Comment: I didn't have a Powershell script for you, but I added a rough demo in VBScript below showing one approach. PhilDW describes another approach. I added a link - towards the bottom - in my answer below to a tiny VBScript which will export a list of installed products with product code and product name to your desktop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **it is normal that the product GUID changes for new versions of the application**, though it is also possible to upgrade some applications without changing the product GUID (referred to as [minor upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370037(v=vs.85).aspx) - as opposed to [major upgrades](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that change the product GUID). What tends to remain stable between different releases of the same product is the **UpgradeCode** (it defines a family of related products). ProductCode uniquely identifies a product (in a specific version).

There are some options for uninstall listed here: **[Uninstalling an MSI file from the command line without using msiexec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450027/uninstalling-an-msi-file-from-the-command-line-without-using-msiexec/1055933#1055933)**.

I suppose you could use the MSI file name as illustrated in `section 3`, or if the product name remains stable you could use it along with automation to look up the correct product GUID to uninstall the product in question. I will test this in a moment and update the answer.

---

**UPDATE**: A sample VBScript to uninstall product by "product name" (assuming it remains constant across releases, which it normally does, but there is no guarantee - it depends on the product).

Find the product name in Add/Remove Programs - or use the tiny VBScript linked to at the bottom of this answer to export a little text file with info for all installed packages.

```vb
' On Error Resume Next ' Used to suppress errors

Const msiUILevelNone = 2
Const msiUILevelFull = 5
Const msiInstallStateAbsent = 2

Set installer = CreateObject("WindowsInstaller.Installer")
Set products = installer.ProductsEx("", "", 7)
installer.UILevel = msiUILevelFull  ' Running with full GUI (if available in MSI)
' installer.UILevel = msiUILevelNone ' Will run uninstall silently, run script with admin rights

' Get the product name from the user
productname = InputBox("Please enter the product name for the MSI package you wish to uninstall:")
If productname = vbCancel Or Trim(productname) = "" Then
   WScript.Quit(0)
End If    

' Iterate over all MSI packages on the box
For Each product In products

   currentproduct = product.InstallProperty("ProductName")

   If LCase(currentproduct) = LCase(productname) Then

      installer.ConfigureProduct product.productcode, 0, 2 ' msiInstallStateAbsent
      MsgBox "Ran uninstall for: " & currentproduct
      Exit For ' End product iteration, assuming only one product needed uninstall

   End If 

Next

Set installer = Nothing

MsgBox "Finished."
```

---

**UPDATE**: You can create yourself a quick list of product codes and product names using VBScript as described towards the bottom of this answer:  [How can I find the product GUID of an installed MSI setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29937568/how-can-i-find-the-product-guid-of-an-installed-msi-setup/29937569#29937569) . This particular VBScript is as simple as it can possibly get I think.

Comment: I didn't have the time to read all of them but every answer I looked at in that post is actually using msiexec. You just aren't calling it yourself.

Comment: In fact the different options use WMI, COM automation, msiexec.exe, Win32 API functions, Powershell / WMI, .NET, and some manual options to kick off those basic technologies from the GUI or third party tools. I guess even `msiexec.exe` uses [**the C++ Win32 installer functions**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) under the hood - so those are the real McCoy. Everything else is just layers on top of those I believe.

Comment: I have used all of those at one time or another. Watch the processes. They all launch msiexec.exe

Comment: Yes, several msiexec.exe processes are normally spawned when performing MSI operations - even when using the down-to-the-metal Win32 C++ functions (just verified). One for the GUI sequence with user credentials, one for the elevated sequence with system credentials, and any number of extra msiexec.exe processes for running custom actions and other components needed by the MSI engine. Once it is an MSI, you need the Windows Installer engine to process it, but it can be invoked in a myriad of ways. Can we ask what the particulars are for your scenario where this is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way that people get around the various ProductCode values in this situation is to start with the more constant UpgradeCode.

Given the UpgradeCode, you can use MsiEnumRelatedProducts (or script or MSI interop equivalent) to return the ProductCode. Code like this typically never needs to be changed.

I'm pretty sure PowerShell should be able to do this.

Answer (score 0):

What do you know that doesn't change, or that does change but you can easily track?

- Say the product code changes, but the upgrade code doesn't. You could follow PhilDW's suggestions to retrieve a product code from that upgrade code using [MsiEnumRelatedProducts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370103) or [Installer.Related](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369476) or equivalent.
- Say the name doesn't stays the same. You could follow Stein's suggestions to find the product code by product name, starting with [MsiEnumProductsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370102) or [Installer.ProductsEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa369461) or equivalent.
- Say you cache a local copy of the installing .msi's in an unchanging location, or one easily found by your script. You could follow 4c74356b41's suggestion to use that path in a command line to msiexec. (Note that [msiexec /x](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988) accepts either a package path or a product code.)
- Say you don't like any of those options. Perhaps you can add a registry value in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\YourCompany\YourProduct, setting a string value ProductCode to `[ProductCode]`. Then you can use `reg query HKLM\Software\YourCompany\YourProduct /v ProductCode`, or equivalent (sorry, I'm a dunce with PowerShell), to fetch the current product code. (At least if you account for 32-bit vs 64-bit paths, of course.)