# MSI Installing twice rather than upgrading with the same UpgradeCode

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, windows-installer

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 with the Installer Projects extension to make an MSI for my app.

However, when I run the, say 0.2.7 MSI on a system with 0.2.5 already installed, it adds another item to the appwiz.cpl, and leaves the version the same, so that after the 0.2.7 install, it just runs the 0.2.5 exe.

I make sure that the UpgradeCode is the same, the PackageCode and ProductCode are changing with each version and I have RemovePreviousVersions set to true.

My source code is available [here](https://github.com/iamtheyammer/gam-cros-win-wrapper). You'll find the installer project in ChromebookGUI/Installer/.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have time to answer thoroughly, but for a major upgrade the Upgrade table must be authored properly and you need a new product GUID and a bump in one of the first three digits of the version number. The action property in the Upgrade Table must be added to the list of SecureCustomProperties. Are you sure you haven't changed the upgrade code?

Comment: To make sure that the UpgradeCode didn't change, I grabbed the one from 0.2.5 and used it on the 0.2.7.

Comment: I added a follow-up answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of upgrade codes for installed packages like this: [How can I find the Upgrade Code for an installed MSI file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46637094/how-can-i-find-the-upgrade-code-for-an-installed-msi-file/)

I have another one that is a bit simpler, but I couldn't dig it up right now. I will have a look later.

Adding this answer to "evolve" it if you provide more follow-up information (to avoid too many comments).

**UPDATE**: the other answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48615123/129130), but I wouldn't recommend that script if you have automatic logging enabled since it will create log files in the temp folder when run.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I’ll be back at work tomorrow to check this out.